# disable reply comments on depth equals 2

Tags: comments

Using budypress and I'm trying to disable comments on comments' comment, meaning depth 2.

The structure would go like this.

Main Comment.
    Someone made a comment   <-- Reply is possible
        Another person made a comment of this reply   <-- No1 can comment this

Any ideas?

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NVM, shame on me, I just realized I can control the depth in the wp options.

Settings -> Discussion ->  Enable threaded (nested) comments 2 depth